# 2023 Pro-Tem Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

elementary OS Stack Exchange last had moderators elected around a year ago. After discussing it with the current moderator team, we're looking at scheduling an election to start sometime in January 2023, in response to some members of the team having been [removed due to inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338006/208518) and the moderation team being below our minimum of 3 mods per team.

**It should be noted that having folks willing to step up and moderate the sites is one of the few requirements we have for keeping sites alive,** and given that we *need* to schedule an election (to bring the moderation team up to the minimum of 3 members), should it fail we'll need to have a discussion about the site's future.

But that's getting ahead of ourselves right now: to avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I'm posting this now to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please post an answer below if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. As I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start sometime in January 2023.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to include your whole election nomination statement.